# Ceiling fan with remote wiring issues

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I have a Hunter ceiling fan and LED light kit that comes with the fan, I purchased the display model so I don't have any wiring diagrams. The fan has ground (green), white, black and black with a white strip on it. I have two switches to control the fan (fan and light). I have ground, white, black, and red. The builder used the white, red, and ground when they installed the basic light.

I also purchased a remote for the fan. There are 4 wires, two to the ceiling and two the fan. The two to the ceiling are black and white and the two to the fan are blue and yellow. The instructions for the remote say to wire black to black, white to white and include the white from the fan (3 wires in one cap). From the remote to fan it says wire blue to blue and yellow to black.

Is it safe to assume that the black with the white strip is considered the blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitions possible that the black with white stripe is the same as blue.  Though you might find that the black is blue, and the black with white stripe is black.

In either case it won't matter, if you get it wrong you'll just have to switch them.

Comment: I tried all combinations and the appears to be kinda working (didn't do a great test as its half assembled on the ceiling).  One issue I have is that the light never comes on. Even with the pull string it never comes on. I have a proximity sensor and both wires are hot when (blue and yellow). I ended up wiring the blue to the black with white strip.

Answer (score 0):

I searched google for Hunter fan install and found a [PDF manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cRmI.png). It may not be correct for you model. They should offer the proper one on their site.

I do not think you use the red wire, marette it and forget it.

The fan has

- green: ground
- black: fan hot
- black-white: light hot
- white: shared neutral

The remote has

- white: shared neutral
- black: remote module power?
- Blue: module control line to fan or light
- Yellow: Module control line to fan or light

No ground to the module, switch is grounded to the fan.

---

The electrician installed the proper wire for a standard install. Shared neutral with a hot per switch/device (fan and light).

You will only need 1 switch with as the remote system needs power but the rest is handled in its circuitry. The second switch can sit dormant, no need to remove it.

It should be mentioned remotes don't like dimmer switches.

As to the lights.  It may be possible the remote you bought is not rated for low LED voltages? Possible you burnt out the control or have something wired funny.

When I did my "remotes" the instruction warned heavily about miswiring causing damage. In a separate room I burnt out a fan controller that had inadequate instruction and non standard wire colouring.

If possible, post your model numbers for both units. I know you said display but it could be on the electrical label.

Not an electrician, just a guy on the internet.